How to get arguments from ArgParser to write to a textfile so it can be read with `fromfile_prefix_chars`
I want a script to save all arguments (whether provided or populate from defaults or read from a text file) to a text file in such a format that I can re-run the script using fromfile_prefix_chars with that file. This is to allow for easy reproducability and store the arguments that were used to generate certain data.
I have a very brittle and incomplete implementation. I'm sure there is a better way but have not found it via google.
Q: how to capture a) all arguments with b) clean and concise code ?
Context
ArgumentParser has a feature that allows the reading of arguments from a text file (fromfile_prefix_chars). There seems little point in reinventing the wheel to read e.g. a JSON file. While the reading of a text file is part of the ArgumentParser feature set, writing that file seems not to be. I am looking for an elegant solution to convert a arg: Namespace and a parser: ArgumentParser into a text file (containing all arguments, not only those passed in at the command line), that can be read using ArgumentParser
Workflow Example

Run script python script.py --count 7  --channel-stdev 17 /somepath
This should produce a text file called args_out.txt with the content

--count
1
--channel-mean
4.5
--channel-stdev
3
/somepath


I can re-run the script using python script.py @args_out.txt

Minimal example
from pathlib import Path
import logging
import argparse
from argparse import Namespace, ArgumentParser
from typing import Optional, List, Tuple


def get_arg_parser() -> ArgumentParser:
    parser = ArgumentParser(description='Test',
                            fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
    parser.add_argument('--count', default=1, type=int,
                        help='Number of ')
    parser.add_argument('--channel-mean', default=4.5, type=float,
                        help='Mean number ')
    parser.add_argument('--channel-stdev', default=3, type=float,
                        help='Standard deviation ')

    # Logging control
    log_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    log_group.add_argument('-v', '--debug', action='store_true', help='Enable debug mode')
    log_group.add_argument('-q', '--quiet', action='store_true', help='Enable quiet mode')

    # I/O control
    parser.add_argument('input', nargs='+', help='Path to a single')
    return parser


def parse_args(arg_list: Optional[List[str]] = None) -> Namespace:
    parser = get_arg_parser()
    return parser.parse_args(arg_list)


def convert_args_to_text(args: Namespace, parser: ArgumentParser) -> str:
    """ Convert an argparse.Namespace object to a list of strings that can be written to a file and then
    read as arguments again. """
    required, optionals, optionals_store_true = get_arg_name_to_argument_dicts(parser)

    text = ''
    for k, v in vars(args).items():
        k_dash = k.replace('_', '-')
        if k_dash in optionals:
            text = add_key_and_value(text, key=k_dash, value=v)

        elif k_dash in optionals_store_true:
            if v:
                text = add_key_and_value(text, key=v, value=None)

        elif k_dash in required:
            text = add_key_and_value(text, key=None, value=v)
        else:
            logging.warning(f"skipping argument {k}")

    return text


def get_arg_name_to_argument_dicts(parser: ArgumentParser) -> Tuple[dict, dict, dict]:
    """ Here I try to extract the argument names and whether they are optional or required from the ArgParser
    This is very brittle FIXME """
    optionals = {}
    optionals_store_true = {}  # These are only added if they are true
    required = {}
    for optk, optv in parser._optionals._option_string_actions.items():
        if not optk.startswith('--'):
            # Skip short options
            continue

        if isinstance(optv, argparse._StoreAction):
            optionals[optk.strip('--')] = optv
        elif isinstance(optv, argparse._StoreTrueAction):
            optionals_store_true[optk.strip('--')] = optv

    for req_group_actions in parser._positionals._group_actions:
        name = req_group_actions.dest
        required[name] = req_group_actions

    return required, optionals, optionals_store_true


def add_key_and_value(text: str, key: Optional[str], value: Optional[Tuple[str, List]]) -> str:
    """ Add a argument key and value to a text block. """

    if key is not None:
        text += f"--{key}\n"

    if value is None:
        return text

    if isinstance(value, list):
        for vi in value:
            text += f'{vi}\n'
    else:
        text += f'{value}\n'

    return text


def main():
    args = parse_args()

    print(args)

    text = convert_args_to_text(args, get_arg_parser())
    with open('args_out.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Thank you for your help

Is the code you presented anyhow relevant? How do you want to deal with newlines in arguments? Why not use an actual fornat, like a json? What is fromfile_prefix_chars?

@KamilCuk The code I present is a working example but it does not support all the argument types supported by ArgParser. As ArgParser has a feature that allows the reading of arguments from a text file, there seems little point in reinventing the wheel to read a JSON file. While the reading of a text file is part of the ArgParser feature set, writing that file seems not to be. I am looking for an elegant solution to convert a arg: Namespace and a parser: ArgumentParser into a text file that can be read using ArgParser

But why argparser? Save the argumetns sys.argv, why do you care about argparse?

Because ArgumentParser is the only place where all the arguments are stored. Some arguments come from the command line, some from the defaults and some from a file. I want to save all of them in such a way that in 6 months I go back and know exactly what the settings of the processing step were.
I can use YAML or JSON for this but then I need to define every argument twice: once in the ArgumentParser and once in the load/save function for the YAML/JSON. If I can avoid repeating myself in every script, I'm sure it will avoid a lot of errors and result in short and cleaner code.

I would say these are not arguments, it's internal settings of your program, and would use dataclasses (or pydantic) to serialize and deserialize your program internal state to/from a file, using JSON as an intermediary format. In other words, I wouldn't represent your program settings as a list of strings, rather as a python object, and even use pickle.

This prefix file feature isn't designed for heavy lifting.  The file values are simply spliced into the sys.argv list at the start of parsing.  It's just a way of supplying a set of oft repeated commandline strings.

How about designing the parser from the start to make this easy?  For example no defaults. mutually_ exclusive might conplicate it.  Fancy nargs, etc

I eventually went with this. Its imperfect but avoids having to define the arguments twice. I'm sure a better solution exists.
def convert_args_to_text(args: Namespace, parser: ArgumentParser) -> str:
    """ Convert an argparse.Namespace object to a list of strings that can be written to a file and then
    read as arguments again using the `fromfile_prefix_chars` argument in the ArgumentParser.

    Currently, only supports optional `_StoreTrueAction` and optional and required `_StoreAction`.
    """

    dest_to_arg = get_arg_name_to_argument_dicts(parser)

    text = []
    for k, v in vars(args).items():
        action = dest_to_arg[k]

        if isinstance(action, argparse._StoreTrueAction):
            if v:
                key = action.option_strings[-1]
                text.append(key)
            continue

        if action.option_strings:  # This is an optional argument
            key = action.option_strings[-1]
            if isinstance(v, list):
                for vi in v:
                    text += [key, vi]
            else:
                text += [key, v]

        else:  # Required argument
            if isinstance(v, list):
                text += v
            else:
                text.append(v)

    return '\n'.join([str(x) for x in text])


def get_arg_name_to_argument_dicts(parser: ArgumentParser) -> dict:
    dest_to_arg = {}
    for action in parser._actions:
        dest_to_arg[action.dest] = action

    return dest_to_arg


def save_arguments(args: Namespace, parser: ArgumentParser, output_dir: str):
    """ Save the CLI arguments to a text file. """
    text = convert_args_to_text(args, parser)

    output_dir_path = Path(output_dir)
    output_dir_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    outfile = output_dir_path / f'args_{dt.now().isoformat()}.txt'
    with open(outfile, 'w') as f:
        f.write(text)


I find your approach confusing. Consider:
import arg
import json
import argparse
import shlex
from pathlib import Path


def dump_args():
   with Path("args_out.txt", "w") as f:
      print(shlex.join(sys.argv[1:]), file=f)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser....
...
dump_args()

Then you can rerun your script using the shell command xargs, which also parses quotes.
xargs ./script.py <args_out.txt

You can also rerun your script from python, with:
with Path("args_out.txt") as f:
    args = parser.parse_args(shlex.split(f.read()))


I haven't come across shlex before, thats a nice module!
This only saves the arguments that are passed explicitly and misses those that are populated from the default values or read from a file.
